# Sum of $2009$ roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

If $1,\alpha _1 ,\alpha _2, .........,\alpha _{2008}$ are $2009$ roots of unity , then the value of $\Sigma ^{2008} _{r=1} r(\alpha _r + \alpha _{2009-r})$

I know sum of all the roots are 0 and product is 1 .

As $x^{2009}-1$

but now how to proceed .

Comment: $\alpha_r = \alpha_1^r$? And $\alpha_1$ is primitive?

Comment: @Exodd what do you mean by that

Comment: I want to know if $\alpha_r$ are all the 2009 roots of unity, and whether $\alpha_r$ and $\alpha_{2009-r}$ are conjugated

Comment: @Exodd yes they all are roots

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have that $$\sum_{r=1}^{2008}r(\alpha_r+\alpha_{2009-r})=\sum_{r=1}^{2008}r\alpha_r+\sum_{r=1}^{2008}r\alpha_{2009-r}=\sum_{r=1}^{2008}r\alpha_r+\sum_{r=1}^{2008}(2009-r)\alpha_r$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: How you have written $ \sum_{r=1}^{2008}(2009-r)\alpha_r$

Comment: @user123733 Well instead of starting the sum at $r=1$ to $r=2008$ you start summing from $r=2008$ downwards to $r=1$.

Comment: So will the answer would be 0

Comment: Yes,since $2009\cdot 0=0$

Comment: @user123733 I don’t understand, could you please elaborate?